# Angularjs can't access parent scope function from directive

Tags: angularjs, scope, parent

I cannot get the parent function call from the isolated scope..The purpose of this code is to create a widget directive which can be used multiple times on the same page... I tried some other option, but doesn't work either. It works using the parent scope.
What am I missing here.

```
var app = angular.module("winApp", []);

app.controller("winCtrl", function($scope, dataFactory) {

    $scope.getData = function() {

        dataFactory.get('accounts.json').then(
                function(data) {
                    $scope.items = data;
                });
    };
});

app.directive("windowSmall", function() {
    return {

        restrict : 'EA',
        replace : 'true',
        scope : {
            type : '&'
        },

        transclude: 'true',

        templateUrl : 'windowtemplate.html',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind("load", function(){
                console.log(attrs.type);

                if (angular.equals(attrs.type, 'getData()')) {
                    scope.active = 'accounts';
                    console.log(attrs.type);

                    // scope.getData();

                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.$eval(attrs.type);
                    }); 
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

app.factory('dataFactory', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function(url) {
            return $http.get(url).then(function(resp) {
                return resp.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
     <div ng-app="winApp" ng-controller="winCtrl">

      <window-small type = "getData()">  </window-small>

     <br> <br>
     <!-- 
        <window-small type = "bulletin"> </window-small>    -->
```

Comment: in your link function calling `scope.type()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **$rootScope** for a full proof solution. Due to the fact that an application can have multiple parents but only one **$rootScope**.

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24rootScope)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your link function with :

link : function(scope, element, attrs) {

```
        element.bind("load", function(){
            console.log(attrs.type);

            if (angular.equals(attrs.type, 'getData()')) {
                scope.active = 'accounts';
                console.log(attrs.type);
                scope.type();
            }
        });
    }
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/X7Fjm/3/